# Specify destination folder for download from an R Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I'm working on a Shiny app, in which the user uploads a file, which is then processed to generate a report, which the user can download as an editable Word .doc.

It works as intended, other than that although a "Save As" dialogue window appears which seems to allow you to choose the destination directory, the resulting .doc file ends up being saved to a temporary directory with a randomly-generated name (this is under Windows).

I suspect this is due to the use of the tempdir command, which is part of using rmarkdown to generate the downloaded file.

How should the below code be amended to allow the destination folder to be chosen?

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)
library(knitr)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput('markdown'),
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Apptitle"),

    # Sidebar with file input
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          fileInput(
            inputId = "file1",
            label = "Select file(s)",
            multiple = TRUE,
            accept = NULL,
            width = NULL,
            buttonLabel = "Browse...",
            placeholder = "No file(s) selected"
          ),
        downloadButton("report", "Generate report")
        ),
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
      
        output$report <- downloadHandler(
          reactive(file <- input$file1),
          filename = "wordreport.doc",
          content = function(file) {
            tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "wordreport.Rmd")
            file.copy("wordreport.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
            params <- list(report.data = input$file1)
            rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = "wordreport.doc",
                              params = params,
                              envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: Fixed, using the solution below, and the code edits suggested here: [Passing a dataframe as a parameter from Shiny app to RMarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71398939/passing-a-dataframe-as-a-parameter-from-shiny-app-to-rmarkdown)

Comment: So do you want to save the file via your web browsers user interface? Or are you trying to write the file on the server side? Normally you write shiny apps assuming that the server is on one machine and the client is connecting from a different machine so they can't see eachother's file system. Web pages have limited to access to your file system for security reasons. The locations the browser can see are different than the locations the server can see normally. Formally in `downloadHandler` you have a command that returns a file, but `render()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: So the way it will work is:
User uploads a .csv file from their computer. Once the upload is complete they will hit a "generate report"* button.
That will cause the R Shiny app to pass the .csv file as a dataframe to the RMarkdown script, which generates a Word document from it.
Then the user gets a "Save file as" popup from their browser, which will let them save the Word document on their computer.

(*I also intend to have a second RMarkdown file show a preview of the report in the Shiny mainpanel before they decide to hit the download button, but that's a question for another time!)

Comment: The report does not need to be saved by the server.

Comment: You need to actually return the file in the `downloadHander`. Try adding `file.copy("wordreport.doc", file)` to the end of the `content=` function.

Comment: Ahh no luck, I'm afraid - it brings up a Save As window, but then doesn't save the file in the location - it goes to a temp folder instead, as before. Perhaps ```file``` is being used too many times?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't set the download location for a file: that's a web browser setting, not something a web server decides.

Comment: @MrFlick `render()` does actually return the path to the rendered file, so that's not the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Mikko Marttila. What I'm hoping is for a dialogue window to pop up that lets the user navigate through their file system and then save the file somewhere helpful. It's OK if it uses the web browser default settings, as that's something they will be used to (and will typically point at the Downloads folder in Windows). But right now the output file silently goes into a temp folder which will be a hassle for them to look for.

Comment: @The_Carthaginian By "silently goes into a temp folder", do you actually mean the copy that's created by the server when you run it locally? Looking at your code, I think you shouldn't have `output_file = "wordreport.doc"` -- it should be `output_file = file`. The job of the `content` function is to create a file with a name given by the `file` argument, which then gets sent for the user to download.

Comment: Hi, @Mikko Marttila, there are two files that appear in the temp folder. One is the wordreport.Rmd, which is the copy created by the server, the other is the actual .doc created.

If I have ```output_file = "wordreport.doc"``` then the .doc appears in the temp folder, and is named "wordreport.doc".

If I have ```output_file = file``` then the .doc appears in the temp folder, and is named "<random string>.doc".

Comment: Yeah, when you run the server locally, the generated files get stored in the temp dir. Do you still have an issue with the download? It sounds like everything should be working now. Have you checked your browser download history to see where the files have been going?

Comment: Ah, so far I've been running the app in a RStudio window. Do you mean that when this is run 'live' then the download function will work as expected?

Apologies, I'm also getting some frustrating object not found errors which are interfering with testing(!).

Comment: @MikkoMarttila But `render()` only returns the path, it doesn't return the contents of the file itself. The `content=` function needs to write data to the `file` connection. The function can't just return a file name.

Comment: @MrFlick yeah you're right, it needs to _write data_ -- and `render()` already does the writing. The return value is actually irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing `reactive(file <- input$file1)` as the `contentType` argument to `downloadHandler()`, which can't be good. Also, you're not writing anything to the `file` given as an argument to the `content` function.

Remove the `reactive(file <- input$file1)` line, and specify `output_file = file` in `rmarkdown::render()`, and your download should work.

As discussed in the comments, you won't be able to have control over the download path though -- that's something the user's web browser and their settings there will decide.

Here's a somewhat more minimal app with a functioning file download, for reference:

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("value", "Some value", 1, 5, 2),
  downloadButton("report", "Generate report")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$report <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "wordreport.doc",
    content = function(file) {
      params <- list(value = input$value)
      rmarkdown::render(
        system.file("examples/knitr-minimal.Rmd", package = "knitr"),
        output_file = file,
        params = params,
        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
      )
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```