# Passing a dataframe as a parameter from Shiny app to RMarkdown

Tags: r, shiny, ms-word, r-markdown

I'm still struggling with some aspects of a Shiny app I'm working on. The intention is that the user uploads a csv file of data, which is then processed to generate a report (from a .Rmd template), which the user can then download as an editable Word .doc.

The .Rmd works fine if I render it in a normal R session. However, if done from my Shiny app, I get the following error:

```
Warning: Error in unique: object 'report.data' not found
  [No stack trace available]
```

report.data should be the dataframe produced by reading the input .csv file. Confusingly, the app does sometimes work (I think this occurs if report.data is already available in the global environment.).

I've tried defining the params in the header of the .Rmd file (see the commented out lines below.) - if I do this then the code runs without an error, but the resulting word document is blank, except for the title.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? Thank you, as ever, for your time in reading this and replying.

And apologies, I feel like I'm making a lot of threads asking for help with what seem to be quite basic things in Shiny, but I do search for similar questions and never find things that are quite right! But once I have these basic things in place I should be able to make progress by myself.

Code to generate a .csv file of example input for report.data:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1234)

product1.parameter1.location1 <- data.frame(
  result = rnorm(25, mean = 2.5, sd = 0.2), 
  product = c("Red Aeroplanes"), 
  parameter = c("Parameter 1"), 
  sample.no = c(1:25), 
  location = c("Factory 1")
  )

product1.parameter1.location2 <- data.frame(
  result = rnorm(25, mean = 2.6, sd = 0.1), 
  product = c("Red Aeroplanes"), 
  parameter = c("Parameter 1"), 
  sample.no = c(1:25), 
  location = c("Factory 2")
  )

product1 <- rbind(product1.parameter1.location1, product1.parameter1.location2)

product2.parameter1.location1 <- data.frame(
  result = rnorm(25, mean = 10, sd = 2), 
  product = c("Blue Trollies"), 
  parameter = c("Parameter 1"), 
  sample.no = c(1:25), 
  location = c("Factory 1")
  )

product2.parameter1.location2 <- data.frame(
  result = rnorm(25, mean = 9.5, sd = 0.75), 
  product = c("Blue Trollies"), 
  parameter = c("Parameter 1"), 
  sample.no = c(1:25), 
  location = c("Factory 2"))
product2.parameter1 <- rbind(product2.parameter1.location1, product2.parameter1.location2)

product2.parameter2.location1 <- data.frame(
  result = rnorm(25, mean = 30, sd = 1.8), 
  product = c("Blue Trollies"), 
  parameter = c("Parameter 2"), 
  sample.no = c(1:25), 
  location = c("Factory 1")
  )

product2.parameter2.location2 <- data.frame(
  result = rnorm(25, mean = 25, sd = 0.75), 
  product = c("Blue Trollies"), 
  parameter = c("Parameter 2"), 
  sample.no = c(1:25), 
  location = c("Factory 2"))
product2.parameter2 <- rbind(product2.parameter2.location1, product2.parameter2.location2)

product2 <- rbind(product2.parameter1, product2.parameter2)

product3.parameter1.location1 <- data.frame(
  result = rnorm(35, mean = 2, sd = 0.2), 
  product = c("Brown Carriages"), 
  parameter = c("Parameter 1"), 
  sample.no = c(1:35), 
  location = c("Factory 1")
)

product3.parameter1.location2 <- data.frame(
  result = rnorm(35, mean = 1.9, sd = 0.15), 
  product = c("Brown Carriages"), 
  parameter = c("Parameter 1"), 
  sample.no = c(1:35), 
  location = c("Factory 2"))
product3.parameter1 <- rbind(product3.parameter1.location1, product3.parameter1.location2)

product3.parameter2.location1 <- data.frame(
  result = rnorm(35, mean = 4, sd = 0.4), 
  product = c("Brown Carriages"), 
  parameter = c("Parameter 2"), 
  sample.no = c(1:35), 
  location = c("Factory 1")
)

product3.parameter2.location2 <- data.frame(
  result = rnorm(35, mean = 3.8, sd = 0.5), 
  product = c("Brown Carriages"), 
  parameter = c("Parameter 2"), 
  sample.no = c(1:35), 
  location = c("Factory 2"))

product3.parameter2 <- rbind(product3.parameter2.location1, product3.parameter2.location2)

product3.parameter3.location1 <- data.frame(
  result = rnorm(35, mean = 10, sd = 1.8), 
  product = c("Brown Carriages"), 
  parameter = c("Parameter 3"), 
  sample.no = c(1:35), 
  location = c("Factory 1")
)

product3.parameter3.location2 <- data.frame(
  result = rnorm(35, mean = 10, sd = 2), 
  product = c("Brown Carriages"), 
  parameter = c("Parameter 3"), 
  sample.no = c(1:35), 
  location = c("Factory 2"))

product3.parameter3 <- rbind(product3.parameter3.location1, product3.parameter3.location2)

product3 <- rbind(product3.parameter1, product3.parameter2, product3.parameter3)

write.csv(product1, "product1.csv", row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(product2, "product2.csv", row.names = FALSE)
write.csv(product3, "product3.csv", row.names = FALSE)

report.data <- rbind(product1, product2, product3) %>% mutate(identifier = paste(product, parameter, sep = " ")) 
write.csv(report.data, "all.data.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

The app.R code:

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
  titlePanel("R Shiny app"),

  # Sidebar with file input
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput(
        inputId = "file1",
        label = "Select file(s)",
        multiple = TRUE,
        accept = NULL,
        width = NULL,
        buttonLabel = "Browse...",
        placeholder = "No file(s) selected"
      ),
      downloadButton("report", "Generate report")
    ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$report <- downloadHandler(
    reactive(file <- input$file1),
    # For PDF output, change this to "report.pdf"
    filename = "report.doc",
    content = function(file) {
      # Copy the report file to a temporary directory before processing it, in
      # case we don't have write permissions to the current working dir (which
      # can happen when deployed).
      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "wordreport.Rmd")
      file.copy("wordreport.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
      # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
      # child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
      # from the code in this app).
      params <- list(report.data = input$file1)
      rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = "wordreport.doc",
                        params = params,
                        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv()))
      file.copy("wordreport.doc", file)
    }
    )

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The .Rmd file (with the lines relating to params declaration commented out):

````
---
title: "Comparison Report  for [CATEGORY] in [MONTH/YEAR]"
output: word_document
toc: yes
#params:
  #report.data: report.data
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE, comment = "", results = 'asis', echo = FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```
#report.data <- params$report.data
```
 my_plot <- function(df) {
    ggplot(df, aes(x = sample.no, y = result)) +
    geom_point(aes(colour = location)) +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(result)), colour = "black", linetype = "dotted") +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(result) + 1.96 * sd(result)), colour = "red", linetype = "dashed") +
    geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(result) - 1.96 * sd(result)), colour = "red", linetype = "dashed") +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
    labs(
      title = paste0("Comparison for ", unique(df$identifier)),
      x = "Sample number",
      y = "Result") +
      #caption = paste0("Caption here.")) +
    expand_limits(y = 0) +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, max(df$sample.no) + 2)) +    
    theme(
      plot.caption=element_text(size=12, hjust = 0, margin = margin(t=20)),
      plot.margin = margin(b=50)
    )
}

```

```{r, comment = "", results = 'asis', echo = FALSE}

purrr::map(unique(report.data$identifier),
                           function(x) {
                             #section heading
                             cat("#", (x), "\n")
                             cat("\n\n")
                             # filter data before passing it to the plot function
                             report.data %>% 
                               dplyr::filter(identifier == x) %>%
                               my_plot() %>% print()
                             cat("\n\n")
                             no.outofbounds <- report.data %>% 
                               dplyr::filter(identifier == x) %>%
                               mutate(outofbounds = ifelse(result > mean(result)+1.96*sd(result)|result < mean(result)-1.96*sd(result), TRUE, FALSE)) %>% 
                               dplyr::filter(outofbounds == TRUE) %>% 
                               nrow()
                             ifelse(no.outofbounds > 0, paste(cat(no.outofbounds), " results greater than 1.96 standard deviations away from the mean."), "All results within 1.96 standard deviations of the mean.") %>% 
                               cat()
                             cat("\n\n")
                             CV <- report.data %>% 
                               dplyr::filter(identifier == x) %>%
                               summarise(CV = sd(result)/mean(result) * 100) %>% 
                               round(2)
                             cat("\n\n")
                             paste("The all-site/factor CV for this parameter is ", CV, "%.") %>% 
                               cat()
                             cat("\n\n")
                             cat("APPROVED/REJECTED.")
                             cat("\n\n")
                             
                           }
) -> results
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. I'll go over them one by one

### Invalid parameter in downloadHandler()

You are passing an object of class `reactive` to the `contentType` parameter of `downloadHandler()`.

```r
downloadHandler(
  reactive(file <- input$file1),     ## <--- here
  filename = "report.doc",
  content = function(file) {
    # ...
  }
)
```

It seems that this messes up the whole logic of `downloadHandler()` and leads to "server error" messages on the client side with no errors or warnings from shiny.

This line needs to be removed in order to download files successfully

### Reference the Rmd-parameter correctly

When you want to access the parameter from the Rmd report, you will need to use `params$report.data`. Just using `report.data` will lead to the following error: `object 'report.data' not found`.

````
---
output: word_document
params:
  report.data: NULL
---

```{r}
report.data <- params$report.data
# ...
```
````

### Fix the path to the generated file

You are knitting the Rmd inside the temporary directory, which is generally a good idea. However, getting the paths right is not always that easy. In your case, I used the following

```r
rendered_report <- rmarkdown::render(
  tempReport, output_file = "wordreport.doc",
  params = params,
  envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
)
file.copy(rendered_report, file)
```

The reason your version didn't work is that the generated report is created inside the temporary directory alogside `tmpReport`. See the reference documentation of `?rmarkdown::render` for more details.

I used the return value of `rmarkdown::render()` instead which holds an absolute path to the generated file. This is less error prone and especially useful if you do not know the file extension of the generated file in advance

### Use read.csv to convert the uploaded file into a data.frame

Shiny doesn't automatically convert uploaded csv files into dataframes. You need to define a parsing logic to do that.

```r
params <- list(report.data = read.csv(input$file1$datapath))
```

### One final word

Try to get more organized with your coding projects and limit the scope of future SO questions to one issue at a time. Creating "minimal reproducible examples" might seem tedious at first, but there are several advantages in doing that

- Other people can read the questions and answers and reuse them in their own projects easily without dissecting a wall of code
- It is much easier to answer those questions. With questions like this, the SO community usually only provides comments because answering them properly requires a lot of effort
- Minimizing and isolating problems is a skill that will help you to figure out issues in your future coding projects much more easily

Comment: Thank you so much for this comprehensive, helpful, and, above all, kind, response. Your comments on preparing minimal examples are gratefully received, and I apologise that in this case, I wasn't able to do so - and see now it's due to some errors I wasn't able to spot. I have a busy day at work ahead, but will work on implementing your changes soon, and will be back here with further questions/comments if necessary. Thank you again.

Comment: Hi @Gregor de Cillia, just writing to confirm that all your suggested fixes have worked. Thank you again!